# Проверка сбощиком почты доменов по популярным стоплистам

Tags: c#, .net, pop3

Здравствуйте, коллеги!
Сейчас делаю небольшую утилиту - сборщик почты. Собирает почту по POP3. Хотелось бы, чтобы доменные адреса с которых пришли письма проверялись по популярным стоплистам типа spamhaus или abuseat (т.е. скачиваю заголовки с сервера, собираю все домены в список и сверяю их с каким-то списком нежелательных доменных адресов, а дальше уже принимается решение отклонять его или нет и т.д.). Дак вот не могу найти актуальную, постоянно обновляющуюся, базу доменов, которые попали в стоплист.  Как это сделать имея на руках только эти сайты (spamhaus и abuseat) я не знаю. На одном из них капча, в другом поле ввода для одного доменного имени. Может быть я плохо ищу, упускаю что-то из виду или есть какой-то другой способ это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если перед кем-нибудь будет стоять такая же задача, то вот решение:

```
request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://ru.myip.ms/files/blacklist/general/latest_blacklist.txt");
response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Тут дело не в запросе/ответе, а в том, что по данной ссылке доступен в текстовом виде актуальный стоп лист и, соответственно, достаточно просто потом с ним работать.